# How to Query for RingOut Call Duration

Tags: ringcentral, ringout

I have a requirement to record the details of calls initiated by RingOut upon completion of the call.  I'm successfully polling the Ring Out Status until the call is finished, but I can't find a way to then query for the User Call Record for the completed RingOut.  Is there a way to get the Session Id for a RingOut call which can be used to retrieve the User Call Record and/or query for a User Call Record using a RingOut Id?  Better  yet, can I create a subscription which will notify my service when a RingOut call is completed?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Polling, try using the push notifications to subscribe for the detailed extension presence event. Within the notification payload, you will be able to detect detect the status of the call.  More information can be found here https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Detailed-Extension-Presence-Event

Hope this help!

[ringcentral](/questions/tagged/ringcentral)